# Can someone explain why Python isn't reading this file?

Tags: python

So I have this code down below. Basically, it should read the lines in testcase.txt and print them out, however it's coming up blank when I run the program. Any solutions to this?

```
testFile = 'testcase.txt'
file = open(testFile, 'r')
index = 0
for line in file:
    test_list.insert(index,line)
    index += 1
file.close()
```

Comment: Does this code run? Do you ever instantiate ```test_list```?

Comment: I don't see a print statement in the code, so not sure why you are expecting it to print anything?

Comment: Not your problem, but use `enumerate()` instead of manually counting indices.

Comment: dont worry i just realised i forgot to add the print statement in for my linked list, thanks for remindning me^^

Comment: Assuming `test_list` starts out empty, your inserts are equivalent to appends with no need to track an index.  So your loop becomes `for line in file: test_list.append(line)`.  This can be made even shorter like so: `test_list = file.readlines()`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to read the documents a bit more regarding python [file objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects)' methods, but here:

```py
filecontents = open('testcase.txt').readlines() 
#readlines automatically splits the file up by linebreaks

for index,line in enumerate(filecontents):
    print(index,line)
```